# Offline file support in OneDrive API via .NET

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Is there some concept implemented in Microsoft Graph OneDrive API that I can leverage for offline files from C#?

I would like to store user files for my app in OneDrive yet this should be also possible when the user is offline. As soon as she goes online there should be some synching going on and files get downloaded/uploaded as needed.

**EDIT**

How is the [scope wl.offline_access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243646.aspx) related to this topic? It sounds promising, but there is little info about it. I suspect it is about using OneDrive while being online but not being signed in. Then it would not be a solution for me. Is this correct?

Comment: Downvoting without leaving a comment is somehow not constructive... [Googling](https://www.google.de/search?q=Offline+file+support+in+OneDrive+API&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=8qDRWNiWDOSv8wfF2KegAQ#q=Offline+files+OneDrive+API&*) was not very helpful, so I posted the question. Maybe I am lacking the right keywords...

Answer (score 1):

You certainly could do this with Graph but you would need to handle tracking and syncing changes within your application. I would highly recommend directing your users to use the [OneDrive app](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-us/download/) rather than attempt to replicate this functionality on your own. Building a fully functioning sync client is non-trivial endeavor to put it mildly.

The `offline_access` scope is used to obtain a Refresh Token so that your server can continue to operate on behalf of the user without requiring the user to be online.